# Presentation Creation Tools

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice, openoffice.org, presentation, tools

Other than LibreOffice/OpenOffice.org Impress what good presentation making tools are available for Ubuntu? I prefer a GUI tool which can export to PDF as I have to make presentation in Windows PC. Can PDF support animations with Adobe Reader 8/9?

I remember reading HTML presentations are often attractive but don't know how to create one. Are there nice tools for that purpose? Can such a presentation run with all effects on an older browser, say IE6/7?

Comment: @chetan you can export presentations as .pdf using libreoffice .

Comment: yeah, that's true. But sometimes I feel LibreOffice is buggy, it keeps crashing at times. So thought of looking for a better option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have the following:

**Scribus** - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribus (Already in the repository)

**LyX** - http://www.lyx.org/ (Already in the repository)

**Sozi** - http://sozi.baierouge.fr/wiki/sozi - A next generation presentation maker that is used as an extension with inkscape to create amazing presentations using SVG format.

And apart from Impress you have Draw in the LibreOffice suite.

All of this can export to PDF (Which is like a normal thing in Linux but not so normal in Windows since you need X or Y program to do it)

UPDATE - Included [Sozi](http://sozi.baierouge.fr/wiki/sozi) which I find a next generation presentation tool. Similar to Prezi.

Answer (score 4):

With [jessyInk](http://code.google.com/p/jessyink/) you use Inkscape to create visually appealing svg presentations, which can be viewed in most web-browsers. PDF-Export is possible, however not the tool’s strength.

Answer (score 1):

This is explicitly NOT a GUI-based presentation tool, but interesting nonetheless and does support export to PDF:

http://code.google.com/p/xsw/

Answer (score 1):

JessyInk is now part of Inkscape (used to be an external plugin) and, thus, offers all the graphic potential of Inkscape, and many other things:

1. Index view while presenting
2. Switch to "draw mode"--> you can highlit/write/draw on your slide
3. Sort of graphic "timer" to show how's your presentation timing going on
4. Zooming to parts of your slide

..and more....

Answer (score 1):

I used [impress JS](http://bartaz.github.io/impress.js/#/bored) . This is html, java script and CSS based.